# The word 'opprobrium'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning

Free Dictionary states that one of the definitions for 'opprobrium' is

> Disgrace arising from exceedingly shameful conduct; ignominy.

Dictionary.com states it means

> the disgrace or the reproach incurred by conduct considered outrageously shameful; infamy.

What I'd like to know is, who feels disgraced when using the word 'opprobrium'. Is it the person who does the shameful act, or do those who know of the shameful act committed by another feel disgraced?

Comment: Disgrace is not exactly something that you feel: it pretends to be "objective", in that you can be a disgrace, and I can say "you are a disgrace", but I can't say "I feel disgrace", or "you feel disgrace". It is like *scandal* or *humiliation*. Of course the question "who determines whether or not this is a disgrace?" is a difficult one: the party using the label claims he knows this objectively, but other might disagree. It is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Are you sure that disgrace is not something that can be felt? Thanks for the response.

Comment: You can feel that something *is* a disgrace, as in "be of the opinion that" it is a disgrcae, but you can't *feel disgrace* as you can feel anger.

Comment: But one can feel _disgraced_. Disgrace. a social status, is not an emotion, so it can't be felt in the same way as emotions are "felt".

Comment: What @Cerberus said. Like beauty, opprobrium is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: How does the reader know who is perceiving the opprobrium?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally the disgrace attaching to a person guilty of dishonourable conduct. Just occasionally it is the expression of disapproval of such conduct.

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford Learner's Dictionary's definition of *[opprobrium](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/opprobrium)* is quite specific:

> severe criticism **of** a person, country, etc. **by** a large group
>   of people

The MacMillan Dictionary defines *[opprobrium](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/opprobrium)* on a more personal level, but still makes the flow of disgrace clear:

> very strong criticism **of** something that **you** do not approve of

As Barrie England stated, the disgrace attaches to the entity that committed the act.